# Laurent series for $f(z) = \frac{\sinh(z + 3i)}{z(z + 3i)^3}$ at $-3i$ (not leaving as a product of series)

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I got this problem in my complex analysis class:

> Find the Laurent series of $$f(z) = \frac{\sinh(z + 3i)}{z(z + 3i)^3}$$ to calculate the residue at $z=-3i$.

Is there an easy way to calculate the series and no leave it as a product of two series?

Comment: Which is the non-easy way? That is, what have you tried or thought of trying?

Comment: You can figure out the coefficient of $1/(z+3i)$ without having to multiply out the series, right?  Have  you computed the two series?

Comment: I mean, i did found the series but it's expressed as a product of two separate series. So i cannot find the residue

Comment: I found the series of sinh(z+3i) and 1/z centered at -3i. And then everything is dividided by z+3i which is already centered at 3i

Answer (score 0):

There's a removable singularity at $z=-3i$, so the residue there is zero.

If you really want to find the Laurent series, write $w=z+3i$. The function is now
$$\frac1{w-3i}\frac{\sinh w}w
=-\frac1{3i}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{w^m}{(3i)^m}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{w^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}.$$
I'd leave it like this ....

Comment: thank you very much, i see that. One thing i've just realized i copied wrongly the function. The (z+3i) factor was actually cube so the functions has a pole. How would you recommend calculating then the residue at the same point

Comment: You'd divide what I got there by $w^2$. You'd then have to find the $w^{-1}$ coefficient, which is the same as the $w$-coefficient in what I have there, viz., $-1/(3i)^2$.